# Null values in SCALA in an Array of String - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: scala, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an Array of String as follows:

```
res17: Array[String] = Array(header - skip me, blk1|X|||||, a|b|c||||, d|e|f||||, x|y|z||||, blk2|X|||||, h|h|h|h|h|h|h, j|j|j|j|j|j|j, k|k|k|k|k|k|k, m|m|m|m|m|m|m, blk3|X|||||, 7|7|||||)
```

This is gotten by a SCALA program, not SPARK with SCALA:

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines().drop(1).toVector) {
   val values = line.split("\\|").map(_.trim)
...
```

When I perform:

```
...
   println(values(0), values(1), values(2))  // giving an error on 2 or indeed 1, if a null is found.
}
```

I.e. it fails if there is nothing between the pipe |.

getOrElse does not help, how can I substitute the "nulls" when retrieving or saving? Cannot see from the documentation. It must be quite simple!

**Note I am using SCALA only, not SPARK / SCALA.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's not the behaviour i am experiencing. Here a screenshot, i may be doing something different:

[image]

Anyway, if you want to get rid of your nulls, you can run a filter like the one below:

```
val values = s.split("\\|").map(_.trim).filterNot(_.isEmpty)
```

If you don't want to get rid but transform them in something else you can run:

```
val values = s.split("\\|").map{x => val trimmed = x.trim; if (trimmed.isEmpty) None else Some(trimmed)}
```

**EDIT**:

```
val values = s.split("\\|").map{x => if (x == null) "" else x.trim}
```

**EDIT** (Again):

I can finally reproduce it, sorry for the inconvenience, i missunderstood something. The problem is the split functions, that removes by default the empty values. You should pass the second parameter to the split function as explained in the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

```
val values = line.split("\\|", -1).map(_.trim)
```

Comment: Need to keep them, will try. the getOrElse seems to not be able to work as I would have thought. Will give it a burl now

Comment: Once you got your empty values as None or Some(whatever) you can use the getOrElse, not before. So in my second example, you'll be able to use that function

Comment: Does not appear to work for me, I have no quotes around s. I tried in scala on databricks and observed no quote. So, no joy

Comment: I can't get why tou have nulls there, but check my edit, it will convert all your nulls in blank strings

Comment: Did you try my edit code?  Did it work any better?

val values = s.split("\\|").map{x => if (x == null) "" else x.trim}

Anyway, yes, if you can provide more info it will be usefull

Comment: Relevant code
// res17: Array[String] = Array(header - skip me, blk1|X|||||, a|b|c||||, d|e|f||||, x|y|z||||, blk2|X|||||, h|h|h|h|h|h|h, j|j|j|j|j|j|j, k|k|k|k|k|k|k, m|m|m|m|m|m|m, blk3|X|||||, 7|7|||||)


for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines().drop(1).toVector) {
       val values = line.split("\\|").map{x => val trimmed = x.trim; if (trimmed.isEmpty) None else Some(trimmed)}
       println(line)
       println(values(0).getOrElse("XXX"), values(1).getOrElse("XXX"), values(2).getOrElse("XXX"))  // giving an error on 2 if null found
}

Comment: Always getting: [error] (run-main-28) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Comment: With this code?

val values = s.split("\\|").map{x => if (x == null) "" else x.trim}

and then printing without getOrElse

println(values(0), values(1), values(2))

Comment: I see a different result, for blk1|X||||| values(0)should be blk1, values(1) ahould be X and the rest are null, that's what I got on my SCALA only program

Comment: yes, as far as I understand, but your results looka  little different to mine I see now

Comment: I am looking at the the stuff per line

Comment: blk1|X|||||
(blk1,X)
a|b|c||||
(a,b)
d|e|f||||
(d,e)
x|y|z||||
(x,y)
blk2|X|||||
(blk2,X)
h|h|h|h|h|h|h
(h,h)

Comment: the above is the line followed by values(0) and and values(1), looks like different result u got

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163552/discussion-between-scouto-and-thebluephantom).